# Python: using packages from a different environment

Tags: python

I have two Python environments installed. EnvA which is my default up to date environment and EnvB which has older versions of some packages used in EnvA.
Is it possible to launch some code based on EnvB from a program running with the interpreter of EnvA?

As a practical example:
I have a pyqt5 GUI which I use to convert my *.ui files, it basically calls the `pyuic5` shell command.
I would like to add the option of converting .ui to pyqt4 code, which is not possible as is, since the `PyQt4` library was replaced by `PyQt5` in this environment.
Is it possible for my main program to execute a script in a subprocess/interpreter/.. with a different python environment, and return once the script has done its job?

Comment: Why not just create a third environment that is configured the way you want it to be? Also, are you using Anaconda, virtualenv, or something else?

Comment: the specific package I'm trying to use is a deprecated version of a package I'm already using in my program, so I don't think it's possible. I've added details on what I'm trying to do in the question.
Also I'm using Anaconda.

Comment: Where did you hear that PyQt4 was deprecated?

Comment: "old" might be the correct term? In any case I can't use Pyqt4 in the same environment as Pyqt5

Comment: You know the path to `pyuic4`, why not just run it with the full path?

Comment: I did not know that was possible, if so it saves me a lot of trouble! I'll try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not really recommended, but you could probably do this by modifying `sys.path`. Just append a path to a package from EnvB earlier in `sys.path` and Python will get pick it up before getting to the EnvA version.

You could also use `importlib` to specifically import from a fully qualified path. This other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path) has some good examples, but basically it looks something like this:

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("module", "path/to/file.py")
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
```